# Why extract returns NAs on the boundary when polygons exactly overlap with the rasters in R?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, polygon, extract

I'm new to GIS and English is not my first language, so apologies for anything inappropriate.

I'm trying to use extract() to get mean values of rasters inside polygons. One of the R codes I used are

```
county_NDVI<-extract(NDVI,province,fun = mean,df = TRUE,weights = TRUE,normalizeWeights = TRUE)
```

The CRS's of *'NDVI'* and *'province'* were different, but I've changed the CRS of 'province' with spTransform so they are the same now. And I have plotted them and checked that they are exactly overlapped. Also the raster data are continuous, so there are not supposed to be NAs.

However, out of 2896 polygons, I got 365 NAs. And I identified the location of all the NA polygons and found that they are all on the bounday of the polygons. So I suspect that the problem has something to do with the boundary or the units of the two objects (*NDVI* and *province*) are slightly different.

Any suggestions on what else I can check or what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Try adding `small=TRUE` to see if this mitigates the problem. If there are small polygons or little overlap, extract can miss underlying pixels. This argument accounts for this issue. Since, by default, extract removes NA's there should not be an issue with spurious NA's in a given polygon causing mean to return NA. However, do keep in mind that many functions will return a NA value if there are any NA's present in the vector. You can use `rm.na=TRUE` to change this behavior. Perhaps pass something like `my.mean <- function(x){ mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) }` to `extract` rather than `mean`.

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans Thanks for your comment. I've tried `small=TRUE`, unfortunately the NA's remain. I'm trying the second method you suggested. The `extract` function takes a while to run.

Comment: You may want to try the `velox` package. It is a notable speed gain in raster extraction. However, it you want to apply weights you will need to write your own function and apply it to the resulting list object.

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans Thanks a lot! The second method worked! I first tried the `my.mean` function, but R returned this warning message: `Warning messages:
2: In .local(x, y, ...) :
  "fun" was changed to "mean"; other functions cannot be used when "weights=TRUE"`. Then I discovered that `extract` also have `rm.na=TRUE`, and it worked. And thanks for recommending the `velox` package. I'll probably not do the extracting things again so I decide not to mess up with other packages for now, but I'll try it if I encounter the same tasks.